# ADF Pipeline Expression Builder Regexreplace

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, expression, builder

I need to know how to formulate an ADF Pipeline Expression for regexreplace, supplying a parameter
@dataset().table_name.

I have the expression:

```
@regexreplace(@dataset().table_name, '[^a-zA-Z0-9_]', '_')
```

The expression builder returns the following error:
Unrecognized expression: @dataset().table_name

I tried to convert the parameter to a string. However the following error is displayed:
Unrecognized expression: @dataset().table_name

Comment: Can you provide details of where you're parameter is defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only have 1 @ symbol at the start of the expression. Try this instead:

```
@regexreplace(dataset().table_name, '[^a-zA-Z0-9_]', '_')
```

Comment: I was able to determine the location on the Connection table name doesn't allow the regexreplace function.